# Performance difference between focal statistics (ArcGIS) and neighbor (GRAS or QGIS)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, performance

I tested minimum, maximum, and average neighbor (circle radius = 161 pixel) using ArcGIS, GRASS and QGIS:

- ArcGIS (10.1): it takes only one minute
- GRASS (6.4.3): it takes 123 minutes for every output
- QGIS (2.8.1): it takes 123 minutes for maximum and average and I have
  no output for minimum

So why does this process takes a lot of time on GRASS and QGIS?
Is there any may to make this process very fast?

Raster type: Aster GDEM with 30m resolution and 16M of pixels

-The number of rows and cols is (X: 3687 Y: 3965)

Comment: Please check if the maps are of the same size in all tests (and edit the post to add the numbers of rows and cols to better understand).

Comment: You might even consider asking why ArcGIS takes the same time for all three operations.  As far back as 15 years ago it was possible to perform the neighborhood mean operation on grids this size in a few seconds (on machines that were much slower than now).  The neighborhood mean operation, which when well coded takes O(N\*log(N)) time for a raster of *N* pixels, ought to be *much* faster than neighborhood extrema, which take O(N\*K) time for neighborhoods with *K* pixels. (K = about 80,000 for a 161 pixel radius; log(N) = about 24 for your grids.)

Comment: thank you for your response, i think that there is 2 hypothesis for this difference. the first one is that the algorithm is not the same and the second one is that the ArcGis algorithm is very optimized.

Comment: And the results are the same?

Comment: very good question, i will verify that

Comment: @markusN, the results are the same, i only want to mention that in QGIS you need to use the diametr of the circle but in ArcGis you use the radius. Thanks